# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR CHANNEL 'master1_test116'' at line 1

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.1

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.56.116', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER='replica1', MASTER_PASSWORD='pass@123', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002', MASTER_LOG_POS=327 FOR CHANNEL 'master1_test116';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR CHANNEL 'master1_test116'' at line 1
> MariaDB [(none)]>

Two mariadb masters having 10.1.48 and 1 slave 10.4.25

Comment: `FOR CHANNEL` was added in 10.7.0. You can't use it in 10.1 and 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/change-master-to/):

> **MariaDB starting with 10.7.0**
> The FOR CHANNEL keyword was added for MySQL compatibility. This is identical to using the channel_name directly after CHANGE MASTER.

So you should write

```
CHANGE MASTER 'master1_test116' TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.56.116', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER='replica1', MASTER_PASSWORD='pass@123', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002', MASTER_LOG_POS=327;
```

Comment: Dear Barmar, Can I add more or 2 database in master_1 if one is already there?

Comment: You can replicate as many databases as you want.

Comment: Dear Barmar Sir, I have added two databases in conf file like binlog_db_db=Test116
binlog_db_db=Test117.  Now I want to ignore some tables as not required in the slave server for the security propouse. how i can ignore?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on configuring master/slave. You should ask a new question in [dba.se].